# instantaneous frequency

Tags: frequency, window-functions

If my signal is

$$
f(t)=\exp[i\phi(t)],
$$
how do I show that

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {\xi}\left|S_f(u,\xi)\right|^2 d\xi = 2\pi\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} {\phi'(t)}\left|g(t-u)\right|^2 dt,
$$

where 
$$
S_f(u,\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)g(t-u)\exp{(-i\xi t)} dt
$$
is the short-time Fourier transform of $f(t)$?

Comment: You might get a better response if you explain a little more where you're getting these equations from and what you hope to get out of it.  As it is, the question is a little sparse.

Comment: Is the greek chsi supposed to be frequency here?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: I believe what the question is asking is: How do I show that the first moment in frequency of the short-time Fourier transform magnitude squared is equal to a smoothed version of the instantaneous frequency ($\phi'$) ?

Comment: Given your signal, it's relatively easy to show that the spectrogram is just the absolute value of the window function squared. Then you just make the substitution that chsi = dpsi/dt and change the range of integration to be over the unit circle rather than R.

Comment: I only know that 
$$
f(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}S_f(u,\xi)g(t-u)\exp(i\xi t) \text{d}u \text{d}\xi
$$ How do I proceed from here?